# Can a mod_rewrite redirect pre-empt a certificate error on a domain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect traffic from an old site to a new site, the https certificate on the old site has expired and i do not want to renew it since it is no longer in use. However, if somebody browses to the old https site they are receiving a certificate error and are not being redirected. The code I have tried is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This is resulting in a certificate warning when somebody browses to `https://www.oldsite.com`

Comment: Not sure, but you may not be able to prevent the certificate warning - it's likely that the browser opens that before even navigating to the domain.

Comment: So the only solution is to purchase a new certificate?

Comment: If I'm correct, probably yes. I'd wait for second opinions, though, I suspect it is so but don't know it for sure. (I'll suggest an edit to the title in a second - as it stands, it looks like the 10.000.000th "how to htaccess" question)

Comment: It depends on how important it is to you. The only solution is to have a **valid** cert or you get that warning and that's by design. You can get a free one from Comodo but it's only good for 90 days. That may be long enough for the transition.

Comment: @Panama Jack, Startssl distributes for free SSL certificate for one year and up to 5 domain.

Comment: @Eugeny its not for me. I pay for my SSL's because I get wildcards and SANs. I was just giving the OP an option. But thanks.